# Редактирование шаблона WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html5

Есть wordpress тема, в которой sidebar подключается кодом:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar('st-blog-sidebar'); ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

В теме кода, касательно sidebar'a больше нет. Подскажите, где находится html/css кода этого sidebar'a, чтобы я мог отредактировать его вид под себя?

Answer (score 1):

То что вы привели - контейнер для вставки виджетов. Их может быть несколько и вставляются они через админку (*Внешний вид*→*Виджеты*). Внешний вид и код виждетов определяются в самом WP, плагинах и темах, но возможно у вас есть только встроенные, поэтому в теме вы о них ничего не находите.

Смотрите что подключено в админке (чтобы узнать как контейнер будет там называться найдите в теме вызов функции `register_sidebar` c `id` равным `st-blog-sidebar`).

Встроенные виджеты находятся в директории *wp-includes/widgets* и подключаются в файле *wp-includes/widgets.php*. Если хотите изменить виджет - лучше скопируйте похожий к себе в плагин и доработайте. Как с этим работать можно почитать, например, [тут](http://easy-code.ru/lesson/custom-wordpress-widgets)

Comment: да, вы правы. У меня виджеты все стандартные. Каким образом их вид можно поменять, где они располагаются? Хотя я понимаю, редактировать стандартные компоненты не есть хорошо, может есть тогда возможность скопировать их непосредственно в тему и там делать с ними все что угодно?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.